# JSF does not call getter methods in popup

Tags: jsf, popup, getter

I have a normal datatable, containing edit buttons, which opens a popup.

```
 <h:form id="creditcard_configuration_form">
  <rich:dataTable id="test" width="100%"
    value="#{creditcardConfigurationService.cardsList}"
    iterationStatusVar="it" var="card">
    <rich:column>
      <a4j:commandLink execute="@this" ajaxSingle="true"
        oncomplete="#{rich:component('test123')}.show()">
        <h:graphicImage value="../../resources/images/edit.gif"
          alt="edit" />
        <a4j:param value="#{it.index}"
          assignTo="#{creditcardConfigurationAction.currentIndex}" />
      </a4j:commandLink>
    </rich:column>
  </rich:dataTable>

  <rich:popupPanel id="test123"
    header="#{creditcardConfigurationAction.currentIndex}"
    onmaskclick="#{rich:component('test123')}.hide()">
        asdf
  </rich:popupPanel>
</h:form>
```

Before opening the popup I set a index-variable in my bean. However, JSF doesn't call the getter method to get the `index` of `a4j:param` when opening the popup (or at least, not anymore). I found out, that the getter-method is called, when the page is rendered, but never after that. (means, that for the popup the index always appears to be 0).

The bean containing the index var is view scoped, while the service bean is session scoped. I am using the newest version of RichFaces (4.3.2 Final) and JSF 2.0.6.

Comment: would be nice, but that does not change anything.

Comment: oh! `index` var mean `#{it.index}` which is in `param` tag,am i right? i predict that you talk about some element which you have put in `popuppanel`.

Comment: Yep, the value of the index var is #{it.index} and its called currentIndex in the bean, like you can see there.
I have some Input Elements and Buttons in the popupPanel, but it does not really matter, since it does not even work, if the popupPanel is empty, like in the example, which i posted above.

Comment: so in this case you can use `action` or `actionlistner` in commandLink and get index value from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is little bit confusing, so i am proving both solution which i am predict as solution for your problem,

**Answer 1 :**
first refer this [link of richfaces show case with demo](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=param&skin=blueSky)
here its code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <h:form>
        <rich:panel>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <a4j:commandButton value="Set Name to Alex" render="rep">
                    <a4j:param value="Alex" assignTo="#{userBean.name}" />
                </a4j:commandButton>

                <a4j:commandButton value="Set Name to John" render="rep">
                    <a4j:param value="John" assignTo="#{userBean.name}" />
                </a4j:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </rich:panel>
        <br />
        <rich:panel>
            <h:outputText id="rep" value="Selected Name:#{userBean.name}" />
        </rich:panel>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

as you can see that you need to `render` any component(here use `rep`), where `name` variable's getter setter called (on page submit param value set in request scope not call getter-setter, it calls only getter on page load time).

**2:**
first check your data is not same as `0` for all Param data from DB,which you can check with put one `outputtext` after `button` with value `#{it.index}` as you use in `param`. 
also one more prediction, change your `commandLink` with `commandButton` as shown in example and try again it may work.

Comment: Haha, so stupid. Thanks for solving the problem (the first solution did it) :)